# How to generate signature with Google Maps python client?

Tags: digital-signature, google-directions-api

I did not find any relevant answer on SO. I can't figure out how to use the Google Maps python client with the *client id* and *client secret*.

The [Maps Python lib doc](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) show in its doc how to instantiate and use the client:

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

directions_result = gmaps.directions("Sydney Town Hall",
                                     "Parramatta, NSW",
                                     mode="transit",
                                     departure_time=now)
```

And links to the documentation on how to generate a client_secret (which is the same as the signature) to [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#client-id).

To generate a signature, we need to encode the API URL we'll be calling with our private key.

This means that

- Before instantiating `Client`, I need to determine myself what URL it is going to call ?
- I need to re instantiate the `Client` each time I make a call ?

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that contrary to what the doc says, the `client_secret` is the private crypto key and not the signature.

This part is wrong:

> For a guide on how to generate the client_secret (digital signature),
>   see the documentation for the API you're using.

[See in the code](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/client.py#L311) that the `client_secret` is used to create a signature.